# Styling a home page image layout - target div or img?

Tags: html, css

I am styling a homepage using image content only, no text.

When I am styling the image layout, should this be done in the div class only (eg. ceiling> or do I need to style each img class (.ceiling > a > img)

Just consicious I am going to deep with the styling here, when it could just be set in the top level div.

http://jsfiddle.net/515r0zw4/

```
<div class="category4block">
<div class="ceiling"><a href="http://example.com/ceiling"><img  src="http://example.com/image/data/Home Page /Ceiling.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="wall"><a href="http://example.com/wall"><img  src="http://example.com/image/data/Home Page /Wall.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="island"><a href="http://example.com/island"><img  src="http://example.com/image/data/Home Page /Island.jpg" /></a></div>
<div class="downwall"><a href="http://example.com/downwall"><img   src="http://example.com/image/data/Home Page /Downwall.jpg" /></a></div>
</div>

.category4block {
width: 100%;
margin-left: -10px;
clear:both;
}

.ceiling {
float: left;
width: 23%;
margin-left: 5px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.ceiling > a > img {
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
max-height: 240px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.wall {
float: left;
width: 23%;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.wall > a > img{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
max-height: 240px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.island {
float: left;
width: 23%;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.island > a > img{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
max-height: 240px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

.downwall {
float: left;
width: 23%;
margin-left: 22px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.downwall > a > img{
border-style: solid;
border-width: 10px;
max-height: 240px;
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: Not clear on what you are asking. Give more detailed info about your problem.

Comment: Like @Paulie_D said, it's really a matter of opinion. Personally I would just target: .ceiling img{}, unless you will ever have a case where an image will appear outside an anchor in that container.

Answer (score 0):

You can just style the 'wrappers', ie: .ceiling, .wall, .island, .downwall

```
.ceiling{float: left; width: 23%; margin-left: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;}

.wall, .island, .downwall{float: left; width: 23%; margin-left: 22px; margin-bottom: 20px;}
```

then you can give the images a particular class which will have the style, eg: image

```
<img class="image" src="YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE" />
<img class="image" src="YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE" />
<img class="image" src="YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE" />
<img class="image" src="YOUR_IMAGE_SOURCE" />

.image{border-style: solid; border-width: 10px; max-height: 240px; width: 100%;}
```